# Conjugacy classes in special linear groups over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $n$ be an integer and $p^k$ a prime power.

**Question:** Is the number of conjugacy classes of elements in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k)$ known?

**Remark:** An answer for $n=2$ would already help me.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps [conjugacy classes in $SL_n(\Bbb F_q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955770/understanding-conjugacy-classes-in-sl-2-mathbbf-q?rq=1) instead? The see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178392/conjugacy-classes-in-sln-q?rq=1).

Comment: No, I really mean $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$.